# How to create Azure Container Registry inside the Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-registry, azure-aks

I am managing K8s cluster with AKS. My main aim to keep all the resources which are required for K8s in the same Vnet.

One of the resources is ACR. I want to make it private and also it should be only able to access within the Vnet.

Please let me know if its possible or point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help please show me the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ACR is just a repository to create and maintain Azure container registries to store and manage your private Docker container images. It seems that there is no Vnet to associate to it. You can follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-intro) to see the feature of it. But it is a private Container Registry, so you can [control the access with Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal).