# Can an Azure Container Registry instance reside in my private Azure VNet so that it's not exposed on the internet?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

Using Azure Container Registry to support Kubernetes service instance.  Is there any way to put the acr instance in my private Azure VNet so that it's not exposed via the internet?  I'm  using  OpenVPN to get into my VNet

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems impossible to put the Azure Container Registry in a Vnet. You just can access the container registry through the Server name. Take a look at another [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53221164/how-to-create-azure-container-registry-inside-the-virtual-network/53221283#53221283) that I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot put the registry on a VNET, but it's on the roadmap in the next few months.

Answer (score 0):

ACR now supports VNET as a preview feature. Please see this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-container-registry-firewall-rules-and-virtual-network-in-preview/